# Memory Error : Training large dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, hdf5, hdf5storage

> memory error

My dataset have 70k images which i want to train through `Conv2D` but it is throwing memory error when i tried to load the dataset. I just have 4GB RAM,  how i can resolve this issue through `HDF5` matrix by creating a dataset in `HDF5`? and then loading it to train, i guess it will take less memory then. I tried some tutorial to create HDF5 dataset but this processes comes after where the error is occurring. What i am doing wrong? Please ask if question is not clear.

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40,
                            width_shift_range=0.2,
                            height_shift_range=0.2,
                          rescale=1./255,
                          shear_range=0.2,
                          zoom_range=0.2,
                          horizontal_flip=True)

batch_size=28
num_classes=37
epochs=100

os.chdir("E:");
path="Dataset/One";
classes=os.listdir(path)
x=[]#Datapoints 
y=[]#labels 
for fol in classes:
    imgfiles=os.listdir(path+u'\\'+fol);
    for img in imgfiles:
        im=Image.open(path+u'\\'+fol+u'\\'+img);
        im=numpy.asarray(im)/255;
        x.append(im)
        y.append(fol)
x=numpy.array(x)
y=numpy.array(y)
#memory error####################################################
x=x.reshape((-1,100,100,1))

n=x.shape[0]
randomize=numpy.arange(n)
numpy.random.shuffle(randomize)
randomize
x=x[randomize]
y=y[randomize]
```

Comment: How large is the total size of the 70k images?

Comment: 15 MB(100 x100) images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to load all the data at once, and it is much larger than your RAM.  You need to load just one batch and process it, then discard that batch and move on.  A natural way to do this might be inside the `for fol in classes` loop--treat each `fol` value as one batch, and fit one batch at a time.

Comment: but i am splitting my dataset after loading all of it if i just take one folder how its going to split

Comment: The problem is you load 100% of the files before processing any of them.  You should load 1%, process them, then load the next 1%....

Comment: how i can load each image or batch of dataset can you show me some simple steps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to access or process all of the data at once then you can load it in `chunks`.

If it's a csv file and if you can use `pandas` then maybe you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
for chunk in pd.read_csv('dataset/movies.csv', chunksize=1000):
    # use this chunk for processing and/or training
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

do not train all dataset together train only few samples as per memory requirement I have experiment with large dataset and train only few samples at a time.

```
train_data = train_data.sample(n=200, random_state=12).copy()
train_data = train_data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

based on requirement you can modify n(numbers of samples) and random states.
random states  used to set a seed for the random number generator. It ensures that the dataset is sampled in a reproducible manner.